# What's the recommended syntax for matching types in Dart 3?

Tags: dart, dart3, dart-pattern-matching

Dart 3 has two syntaxes for matching types:

```dart
switch(myObject) {
  case TypeA(): // With parameter destructuring
  case TypeB _: // Without parameter destructuring
}
```

If no further destructuring is needed, which should be used? Is one more performant than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll recommend `case TypeB _:` as the general way to write type tests that do nothing else.

The reason is that it allows any type syntax, where `TypeA()` only allow type *names*, so if you ever need to match a function, you can write it directly as:

```dart
  case void Function() _: .... // Works
```

You can use `()` for any type as well, you just need a helper type alias, so the type has the correct format:

```dart
typedef typeof<T> = T;
// ...
  case typeof<void Function()>(): ... // Works too.
```